# Error in sending an email with BLAT

Tags: email, batch-file, blat

I have this code:

```
blat -to test@test.com -server -f test@test.com -subject "subject" -body "body" -attach DATA.log
```

It uses blat to send a email but it gives the error:

> Not enough arguments supplied

Does any one know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this :

The server is setted here for GMX. You have to set it for your provider.

```
blat.exe -server SMTP.GMX.COM -f your_E-mail_address -to Destination_E-mail_adress -s "cc text" -body "body text" -u "Login of your E-mail" -pw "Password of your E-mail"
```

http://www.blat.net/syntax/syntax.html

And here a list of the most commons SMTP and POP Servers :

http://www.arclab.com/en/amlc/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html

Edit :

Apparently you'll need [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) to provide the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) as required by GMail.

You can also try with an another provider like GMX who worked for me.

Or you can try Mailsend :

https://github.com/muquit/mailsend/

Comment: What's your E-mail provider ?

Comment: Thanks sorted it now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to send via mail() check the error log. You have to add an authenticate method with the port number and security type.
you can find all free SMTP server list here: https://www.weblydigital.com/free-smtp-server-list-public-smtp-host/