# IP address of the SMTP GMAIL

Tags: windows, batch-file, smtp, gmail, blat

would you know what is the IP address of the SMTP GMAIL
(It allows you to send mail from a batch windows)

```
@echo off

set repertoire="C:\Mon repertoire\"
set emetteur=email.emmeteur@domaine.com
set eMail=email.destinataireg@domaine.com
set copie=-cc destinataire.copie@domaine.com
set subj=-s "Titre de mon message"
set server=-server smtp.domaine.com
set x=-x "X-Header-Test: header supplémentaire optionnel inséré dans le mail"
set debug=-debug -log envois-mails.log -timestamp

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D %repertoire%*.log') DO set fichier="%repertoire:"=%%%i" && GOTO DONE || GOTO DONE
: DONE

blat %fichier% -mime -8bitmime -to %eMail% %copie% -f %emetteur% %subj% %server% %debug% %x%
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Why use the ip-address, when you can use the domain name?

Comment: I tried it but I still have a problem ! here is the error: 2014.07.21 11:15:16 (Mon): The SMTP server does not like the sender name. Have you set your mail address correctly?

Comment: And why do you think it would be different if you used an IP-address? The server would still complain.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\User>nslookup -type=ALL gmail.com
Server:  vodafonemobile.vmb
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com       internet address = 74.125.237.181
gmail.com       internet address = 74.125.237.182
```

Is the way to find out.

You can also type these to get all info on gmail

```
@nslookup -type=A gmail.com
@nslookup -type=AAAA gmail.com
@nslookup -type=A+AAAA gmail.com
@nslookup -type=ANY gmail.com
@nslookup -type=CNAME gmail.com
@nslookup -type=MX gmail.com
@nslookup -type=NS gmail.com
@nslookup -type=PTR gmail.com
@nslookup -type=SOA gmail.com
@nslookup -type=SRV gmail.com
```

Comment: I tried it but I still have a problem ! here is the error: 
2014.07.21 11:15:16 (Mon): The SMTP server does not like the sender name. Have you set your mail address correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Using Blat with gmaill you have to use stunnel.

Take a look here :

[Error in sending an email with BLAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364876/error-in-sending-an-email-with-blat/24365039#24365039)

Comment: thank you but i still have a problem, here is the error:
The SMTP server did not accept Auth PLAIN value.
Are your login userid and password correct?